# How to use 'could' in following sentences?

Tags: modal-verbs, backshifting

I have two examples:

> 1. ‘I haven't been able to find my keys for two years. (which means I don't have them now)
> 2. ‘I hadn't been able to find my keys for two years. (which means I finally found them)

But how should I write them if I want to replace *be able to* with *could*?

> 3. ‘I couldn't have found my keys’
> 4. ‘I couldn't had found my keys’

Is it correct? I think the second one is incorrect. So is there any correct form of it?

Answer (score 3):

This is my understanding of what your example sentences mean:

> 1. I haven't been able to find my keys for two years. (which means I don't have them now, or that I have just found them) (Present Perfect)
> 2. I hadn't been able to find my keys for two years. (which means that there was a period of time in the past, prior to some other past event or occurence, during which I was not able to find my keys. It is possible that I still haven't found the keys) (Past Perfect)

Now, could we replace *be able* with **could**?

1. Sentence 1 is built using the Present Perfect tense, which is formed thus: HAVE + [verb in the past participle form]: "haven't + been".

This scheme is impossible with **could** because it is a special form of verb: an auxiliary verb. It is a past-tense form of the verb **can**.

Auxiliary verbs are "[defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb)". The verb **can** has no participle forms: you can't say "I had **canned** play tennis but then I broke my leg" or "I am **canning** to dance!". So we can't take **have** (or **had**) and add the past participle of **can** to it, since there's no such thing.

When you add **have** after **could**, it has an effect quite unlike that of the Present Perfect. The construction serves to express disbelief about a past event or action:

> You couldn't have done it! (I express disbelief in what you did. )
>   I couldn't have found my keys! (I express disbelief in that I have found my keys)

Your example 4 is easier to explain: we do not use **had** after **could**, so

> I couldn't had found my keys.

..is ungrammatical.

---

What could we do with **could**? Only one thing:

> I could not find my keys for two years.

What would be the meaning? In the past, there was a 2-year period during which I wasn't able to find my keys. Do I have the keys now? Who knows! How long ago did this 2-year period end? Who knows! So it's better to use **be able to** to express more "advanced" meanings.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and getting my point. This question came to my mind to know how to show a period of 'being unable' from a point in the past till now (present perfect) and from a point in past until some other point in the past (past perfect)
So you mean that we should use ‘I couldn't find my keys for two years’ in both cases.
Now how can we distinguish the difference? So you suggest not to use 'could'. Am I right?

Comment: @vahid3561 - the point is that with **could** you would glean no difference from the sentence itself: you would have to guess from the context (from the sentences that go before and after the sentence with **could**). That's why there is such an expression as **be able to**: it can participate in the Present Perfect and Past Perfect constructions, allowing to pack more information in the sentence.

Comment: You're welcome, @vahid3561!

Answer (score 0):

I am not native but as far as I know

could + have +past participle form has meaning of past form of possibility

> It could have been worse ( but it did not become worse)